# Why .ogv doesnt play on Firefox?

Tags: html, video

This is my code:

```
<div class="fascia-animata-video">
    <video>
        <source src="/video/myvideo.secondversion.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    </video>        
</div>
```

but it won't play on Firefox. If I drag/n/drop the video, it plays fine. So what's wrong with this "video" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the codecs, let the browser work it out for itself.

```
<source src="/video/myvideo.secondversion.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
```

Are you running this on a local server? From what you've said below, you need to tell your server how to serve .ogv files.

If you have access to the .htaccess file, add:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
```

Comment: Nothing change. Firefox console says "Content-Type" HTTP "text/html" it is not supported"

Comment: It's `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: No, I'm online. I'm from C# / .NET, there is not htaccess, just web.config.

Comment: Well, I added `<mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogv" />` to the webconfig, but I have the same troubles...

Comment: But now it said `Content-Type" HTTP "video/ogv"` is not supported: somethings is changed, but still doesnt work

Comment: The MIME type should be `video/ogg`, not `video/ogv`.